# Jupyter Notebook extensions within Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Is it possible to use notebook extensions (`nbextensions`) within Jupyter Lab?

I think my extensions are enabled... I call `jupyter nbextension enable` on them beforehand. But I don't see them in notebooks from within Jupyter Lab.

Comment: @grisatis, Jupyter nbextensions are not compatible with Jupyterlab - the notebook extensions relied too much on globals and injecting inline JS. Jupyterlab, on the other hand, has a well documented [extension API](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html). I'm not sure what extensions you are looking for, but you can search for the github topic [jupyterlab-extension](https://github.com/topics/jupyterlab-extension)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use a Notebook Classic extension in JupyterLab.

Though a great deal of effort has been made to make the notebook UI in JupyterLab look and feel like the UI in Notebook Classic, on the backend they do not share a code base. Thus, `nbextensions` for Notebook Classic have zero fundamental compatibility with JupyterLab. Beyond that, as @madhu94 points out, the extension API (how extensions should be structured, required methods, etc) are completely different in Classic and Lab.

There are some examples of projects with both an `nbextension` for Notebook Classic and a `labextension` for JupyterLab (eg [`jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets`](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets)). In these cases the project will have separate code for each kind of extension.

Comment: do you recommend using jupyerlab or jupyter notebook?  They are very similar but very different at the same time......

Comment: @LukAron As a former power user and current developer of all things Juptyer, I would strongly recommend that you use JupyterLab. You can do everything in JupyterLab that you could do in NB Classic. And a whole lot more, but you don't have to; engaging with the extra functionality in JupyterLab is entirely optional

Comment: @LukAron And if there is something that you could do in NB Classic that you can't in JupyterLab, please file an issue [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues). We consider gaps in parity/functionality between jlab and classic to be bugs

Comment: @tel, what is JupyterLab's extension/widget similar to Jupyter Notebook's [python-markdown](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/python-markdown) extension?

Comment: @GustavoReis that's off topic for this thread. Your best bet for getting good answers to similar questions would be https://discourse.jupyter.org/

Comment: This list: https://jupyterlab-contrib.github.io/migrate_from_classical.html  contains labextension equivalents, or alternatives, to popular nbextensions.